Is there a theory of fundamental groups for $C^*$-algebras instead of topological spaces?
Is it possible to construct a theory of fundamental groups $\pi_1 (A,a_0)$ for pointed $C^*$-algebras $(A,a_0)$ instead of pointed topological spaces $(X,x_0)$ : $\pi_0 (X,x_0)$ ?
If the answer is yes, is $\pi_1 (A,a_0) = [C^0(S^1 , \mathbb{C}) , A]_* $ in this case ?
$C^0(S^1 , \mathbb{C})$ is the $C^*$-algebra of complex continuous functions.
$[A , B]_* $ is the set of homotopy-equivalence classes of pointed $C^*$ - morphisms $ f \ : \ (A,a_0) \to (B,f(a_0)) $.
Thanks in advance for your answers.

The relationship between topological spaces and $C^{\ast}$-algebras is contravariant so you'd want to take the maps going the other way. You can just write down a definition in terms of $C^0(S^1, \mathbb{C})$ but it immediately factors through the abelianization so for noncommutative $C^{\ast}$-algebras it's not so interesting.

Thank you for your answer Sir. Can you tell me explicitely why is for noncommutative $C^*$-algebras, it's not interesting ? I don't understand why it is not interesting.

If $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space, then a continuous map $\gamma : S^1 \to X$ dualizes to unital $\ast$-homomorphism $\gamma^\ast : C(X) \to C(S^1)$; compose this with evaluation $\epsilon_z : C(S^1) \to \mathbb{C}$ at $z \in S^1$, and you get a unital $\ast$-homomorphism $\epsilon_z \circ \gamma^\ast : C(X) \to \mathbb{C}$. However, many interesting noncommutative $C^\ast$-algebras admit no or few unital $\ast$-homomorphisms to $\mathbb{C}$, which makes a naïve adaptation of the fundamental group via Gel'fand duality not particularly useful.
